# SQL Select unique user_id from single table

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

How would I SELECT the USER_ID where there is a value or "Retailer" and "Colorado". In other words, the query should result in 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use aggregation and a `having` clause:

```
select user_id
from table t
group by user_id
having sum(value = 'Retailer') > 0 and
       sum(value = 'Colorado') > 0;
```

Comment: Gracias Senor. I knew it was something like that just couldn't quite get there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
SELECT user_id
FROM table_name T
WHERE value IN ('Retailer','Colorado')
GROUP BY user_id
HAVING COUNT(user_id)>1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use `SELECT DISTINCT` to get unique user_id like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `user_id`
FROM tablename
WHERE  `value` IN( 'Retailer', 'Colorado' );
```

The `DISTINCT` keyword can be used to return only distinct (different) values.

Comment: "Retailer" **and** "Colorado".